# Как проверить что триггер ни с чем не соприкосается ( Unity2D )

Tags: unity3d

У объекта есть триггер  и его цель при наличие объекта выполнял действие, а при отсутствие объектов другое действие (просто я знаю только через onTrigger,а он работает только при соприкосновение)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте это.

```cs
bool hasContact = false;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
   hasContact = true;
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
   hasContact = false;
}
```

Только ставьте это на ваш объект.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую сделать как вы подсказали.

Comment: Второй способ не работает

Comment: Ну там блин надо еще проверку в Update писать на  hasContact, а это наверное немного не правильно,оптимизация может страдать

Comment: If(hasContact){}

Comment: ну если хотите без проверки сразу в`OnTriggerEnter` пишете

Comment: А он работает только при наличие соприкосновения, а у меня может случай когда не будет обьекта к которому он будет соприкосатся

Comment: При соприкосновении любого объекта `OnTriggerEnter` автоматически работает, `OnTriggerStay` проверяет и вход и выход, а `OnTriggerExit` работает при выходе

Comment: Тогда используйте `OnTriggerStay`. Вот [ссылка](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerStay.html)

Comment: И к тому же от одной проверки if практически ничего не меняется. Можете спокойно его использовать.

Comment: Я же веть писал что он работает только при соприкосновнии

Comment: А что должен случится если объекта не будет?

Comment: Либо развернутся , либо идти вперед (работает на вероятности),а когда объект есть Либо развернутся , либо сломать объект и идти вперед

Comment: Ну вы можете проверять если ваш этот объект отсутствует то будет идти вперёд...

Comment: создавайте список этих объектов и если их количество 0 то делает определённое движение